# Unable to create and attach a public IP to a VM by terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am getting the below error when I try to create a public ip

```
2019-05-27T03:07:44.5185437Z * azurerm_network_interface.tf-ni-erx-sqlcl1[1]: Resource 'azurerm_public_ip.tf-pip-erx-sqlcl1' not found for variable 'azurerm_public_ip.tf-pip-erx-sqlcl1.id'
2019-05-27T03:07:44.5186152Z * azurerm_network_interface.tf-ni-erx-sqlcl1[0]: Resource 'azurerm_public_ip.tf-pip-erx-sqlcl1' not found for variable 'azurerm_public_ip.tf-pip-erx-sqlcl1.id'
2019-05-27T03:07:44.5186473Z * azurerm_network_interface.tf-ni-erx-sqlcl2: 2 error(s) occurred:
2019-05-27T03:07:44.5186558Z 
2019-05-27T03:07:44.5186910Z * azurerm_network_interface.tf-ni-erx-sqlcl2[0]: Resource 'azurerm_public_ip.tf-pip-erx-sqlcl2' not found for variable 'azurerm_public_ip.tf-pip-erx-sqlcl2.id'
2019-05-27T03:07:44.5187360Z * azurerm_network_interface.tf-ni-erx-sqlcl2[1]: Resource 'azurerm_public_ip.tf-pip-erx-sqlcl2' not found for variable 'azurerm_public_ip.tf-pip-erx-sqlcl2.id'
```

My terraform code is as below:

```
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "tf-pip-erx-sqlcl1" {
  count                     = "${var.count_sqlcl1_vm}"
  name                      = "${var.sql_base_hostname}${format("%02d",count.index+1)}-pip01"
  location                  = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-erx-external.location}"
  resource_group_name       = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-erx-external.name}"
  allocation_method         = "Dynamic"
}
# Network inteface for sql
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "tf-ni-erx-sqlcl1" {
 count               = "${var.count_sqlcl1_vm}"
 name                = "${var.bussvc_base_hostname}${format("%02d",count.index+1)}-nic01"
 location            = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-erx-external.location}"
 resource_group_name = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-erx-external.name}"

ip_configuration {
    name                          = "${var.sql_base_hostname}${format("%02d",count.index+1)}-iip01"
    subnet_id                     = "${data.azurerm_subnet.tf-sn-erx-sql.id}"
    private_ip_address_allocation = "${var.env=="msdn"?"dynamic":"static"}"
    #private_ip_address            = "${var.env=="msdn"?"":"10.112.3.${count.index+10}"}"
    public_ip_address_id          = "${azurerm_public_ip.tf-pip-erx-sqlcl1.id}"
}
}
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "tf-pip-erx-sqlcl2" {
  count                     = "${var.count_sqlcl2_vm}"
  name                      = "${var.sql_base_hostname}${format("%02d",count.index+1)}-pip01"
  location                  = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-erx-external.location}"
  resource_group_name       = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-erx-external.name}"
  allocation_method         = "Dynamic"
}
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "tf-ni-erx-sqlcl2" {
 count               = "${var.count_sqlcl2_vm}"
 name                = "${var.sql_base_hostname}${format("%02d%s",count.index,var.count_sqlcl1_vm)}-nic01"
 location            = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-erx-external.location}"
 resource_group_name = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.tf-rg-erx-external.name}"

ip_configuration {
    name                          = "${var.sql_base_hostname}${format("%02d",count.index+1)}-iip01"
    subnet_id                     = "${data.azurerm_subnet.tf-sn-erx-sql.id}"
    private_ip_address_allocation = "${var.env=="msdn"?"dynamic":"static"}"
    #private_ip_address           = "10.112.3.${count.index+15}"
    public_ip_address_id          = "${azurerm_public_ip.tf-pip-erx-sqlcl2.id}"
}
}
```

I'm unable to understand what is the issue, I specifically added "depends_on" to network interface , ip configuration block like below

```
depends_on                    = "[azure_public_ip.tf-pip-erx-sqlcl2]"
```

The idea behind to do so is to ensure public ip is created before network interface resource is created but unfortunately that does not help either.

It reports error as below,

```
Error: azurerm_network_interface.tf-ni-erx-sqlcl2[1]: ip_configuration.0: invalid or unknown key: depends_on
```

Any assistance would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the error, since your resource "azurerm_network_interface" has count, you could change the `public_ip_address_id`  like this with [element](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/element.html) function:

```
public_ip_address_id          = "${element(azurerm_public_ip.tf-pip-erx-sqlcl1.*.id,count.index)}"
```

and

```
public_ip_address_id          = "${element(azurerm_public_ip.tf-pip-erx-sqlcl2.*.id,count.index)}"
```